# How to search for *public* code within a GitHub organisation I'm a member of?

Tags: github

I'm a member of a GitHub organisation, call it "ACME" (this is not the actual org, just an example name). The organisation has a lot of repos, both public and non-public. I'm trying to work out whether a specific string (say, "MY_SECRET") occurs within any of the *public* repositories. Things I've tried so far:

1. [Search for the code string in the organisation](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aacme%20MY_SECRET&type=code) while logged in. This gives a lot of results, and it's pretty likely all of the results are in non-public repos.
2. Repeat the search above while not logged in. Unfortunately GitHub doesn't allow searching through code without logging in:

   > Before you can access our code search functionality please sign in or create a free account.
3. Use the ["is:public" search qualifier](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Apublic+org%3Aacme%20MY_SECRET&type=code). Unfortunately this does not apply to searching through code, only to finding the repositories themselves.

Possible workarounds:

- Just manually trawl all the results from step 1 above.
- Cobble together some code to get the API response (presumably including pagination) corresponding to step 1 above and filter it with `jq`. This would be reasonable if I had to do this more often.
- Create a new GitHub user without organisation membership to do the search in step 2 above. This is silly.
- Cancel my membership in the organisation to be able to get the relevant results when doing the search in step 1 above. This is very silly indeed.

Is there a more convenient way to search for code in only *public* repositories in an organisation I'm a member of?

Comment: 1. Get a list of public repos to a `.txt` file. 2. For each repo-name in that `.txt` file, use GitHuib Code Search via Puppeteer or `wget`/`curl` (assuming you can make it work with a normal GitHub browser cookie). 3. Concat results.